# How to use Search domain Http API provided by reseller club

Tags: api, http, search, dns

I have been provided the reseller club http api for the domain search.The url is as follows:

https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=0&auth-password=password&domain-name=domain1&domain-name=domain2&tlds=com&tlds=net

Now I am not undersatnding how to use it and what it should be inplace of test.httpapi.com

and also when I use my domain name say

for 
www.x.in

I use 
x.httpapi.com with the valide parameters which makes the url

https://x.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=xxxx&auth-password=xxxxx&domain-name=test.com&domain-name=test2.com&tlds=com&tlds=net

It shows ssl error and when

www.x.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=xxxx&auth-password=xxxxx&domain-name=test.com&domain-name=test2.com&tlds=com&tlds=net

It shows ngix error

Please suggest

Answer (score 8):

You can find most of this information buried inside the [ResellerClub HTTP API Documentation](http://manage.resellerclub.com/kb/answer/744), however, here is what you need to do in order to get going.

There is nothing wrong with the URL. That is the testing URL for them.

https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=0&auth-password=password&domain-name=domain1&domain-name=domain2&tlds=com&tlds=net

...is the URL to check availability of domain names. You are supposed to replace the auth-userid parameter with your ResellerClub User ID (you can get this from the reseller control panel) and the auth-password parameter with you password.

If your user ID is *123456* and password is *albatross* then the URL will look like:

```
https://test.httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=123456&auth-password=albatross&domain-name=google&tlds=com&tlds=net
```

This URL will output JSON on your browser screen.

This URL is not working because you need to add your IP address to the list of white-listed IP addresses to make API calls. You can find this setting inside your ResellerClub control panel. Go to **Settings -> API** and add your IP address. Within 30 minutes, this URL will start spitting JSON.

To use it within your code, you need to white-list the IP for your server within your control panel and make a CURL call or open a socket connection or something.

Let me know if this post helped.

Comment: That' s a fantastic answer.

Comment: but its not showing domain amount